# C++ variables losing values when passed to function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am creating program to calculate math expression `ax^2 + b*x + c`, `a,b,c` are passed to `quadraticExp()` and `x` is passed from `quadraticExp(a,b,c)(x)`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<cmath>

auto quadraticExp(double a, double b, double c) -> std::function<double(double)>
{
    //return auto f1 [&] (double x) -> double   
    return [&] (double x)
    {
        std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<x<<std::endl;
        return ( a*std::pow(x,2) + b*x + c );
    };
}

int main()
{
double a={1.0}, b={1.0}, c={1.0}, x={3.0}   ;
std::cout<<quadraticExp(a,b,c)(x)<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
1 8.00798e-307 1.83847e-307 3
9
```

- So variables `b,c` are losing their values. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of that?
- Can I write full definition of lambda object `//return auto f1 [&] (double x) -> double` so I can reuse `f1` in the function?

Comment: What's the scope of `a`, `b` and `c`? Don't you think capturing their reference is risky?

Comment: Where do you want to re-use it? You can already do `auto f1 = quadraticExp(a,b,c)` in main, then use it like `f1(x);`

Comment: You are returning lambda that binds the parameters a, b, c via reference&. Those are local to quadraticExp function and are out of scope when function returns. So you get lambda which references lost parametes. Bind by value via [=] should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So variables b,c are loosing their values. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of that?

Try with

```
// .....v
return [=] (double x)
{
    std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<x<<std::endl;
    return ( a*std::pow(x,2) + b*x + c );
};
```

I mean... if you pass `a`, `b` and `c`, in the lambda function, as **references**, they are invalid when the `quadraticExp()` function terminate. So, when you call the lambda (outside `quadraticExp()`) the values for `a`, `b`, `c` inside the lambda function are undefined.

You have to pass they by **value**, that is (to make it simple) use `[=]` instead of `[&]`.

> Can I write full definition of lambda object //return auto f1 [&] (double x) -> double so I can reuse f1 in the function?

Not sure to understand... do you mean something like this? [caution: code not tested]

```
auto quadraticExp (double a, double b, double c)
   -> std::function<double(double)>
 {
   auto f1 = [=](double x)
    {
      std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<x<<std::endl;
      return ( a*std::pow(x,2) + b*x + c );
    };

   f1(42); // use of f1 inside the function

   return f1;
}
```

Comment: @ee557725 - not sure to understand your second point but... answer modified

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.